# How to query log to get out all of pull rugged project?

Tags: go-ethereum

There are many meme token are created at ethereum network, and most are pull rugged project, they create a meme token and remove liquidity when people bought.

For example, there is a remove liquidity transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x07881d7d5f9479020e2a823cbd2c6bf9609f35ed4876a4077e70a13a7157251f

This transaction has 9 log events, So I think if transaction contain those 9 log events most are "remove liquidity" transaction, And I wanna to query out those log with ordered topic:

```
v2query := ethereum.FilterQuery{
    FromBlock: big.NewInt(15639422),
    ToBlock:   big.NewInt(15640422),
    Topics: [][]common.Hash{
        {
            common.HexToHash("0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925"),
        },
        {
            common.HexToHash("0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"),
        },
        {
            common.HexToHash("0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"),
        },
        {
            common.HexToHash("0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"),
        },
        {
            common.HexToHash("0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"),
        },
        {
            common.HexToHash("0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1"),
        },
        {
            common.HexToHash("0xdccd412f0b1252819cb1fd330b93224ca42612892bb3f4f789976e6d81936496"),
        },
        {
            common.HexToHash("0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"),
        },
        {
            common.HexToHash("0x7fcf532c15f0a6db0bd6d0e038bea71d30d808c7d98cb3bf7268a95bf5081b65"),
        },
    },
}
```

But I got a error message with:

```
400 Bad Request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32602,"message":"invalid 1st argument: filter 'topics': array size cannot exceed 4"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this is a tx call to UniswapV3 contract. But the issued here might be, you wanna find the calling method is related functions like 'removeLiquidity()', 'withdraw()'...etc.

In this example, because of the structure of Uniswap V3, the method call is called 'multicall()' function. That means this is a Swap behavior rather than remove liquidity.

[image]

If you want to see those revmove liquidity behavior, you can tried to get all the tx records. For example, you can find those record on [Dune](https://%20Dune.com) or [BitQuery](https://graphql.bitquery.io/ide)

Comment: The question is about how to use `FilterQuery` with more than four topics.